# SSRS - multiple groups in a stacked chart

Tags: reporting-services, graph, charts, business-intelligence

Is there any way to have multiple groups in a 100% stacked chart?

My data is just "Site", "Timer", "RunDate", and "AvgDailyDuration"

"Site" is the main group while "Timer" is a subgroup, so there are multiple timers for each site.  For each "Site" I would like a stacked group of timer durations by date.

In my chart data I have:
Values: "AvgDailyDuration"
Category Groups: "RunDate"
Series Groups: "Site", "Timer"

This just combines all of them into one stacked group regardless of the series groups.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a parameter to control the toggle of each group.  Example is to create parameters.  Go to the available Values and place the label as yes with a value of 2 and another label as No and a value of 1.  On the default values tab you can specify wither to have it expand or not (i.e. 1 would be the value for not expanding.:

Available Values
         Label           Value
         Yes             2
         No              1

Then you can insert an expression on the Group's Visability tab adn insert the expression for the third option (i believe) for Show based on expression:

=IIF(Fields!Dataset.Value, = 2, False, True)

DONT FORGET THE SPACES!

Hope that helps.